# Writing From Spark to DynamoDB

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use spark to grab a file from amazon s3 (in the form of a DataFrame or an RDD), do some simple transformations, and then send the file to a table on DynamoDB.

After reading a few other forum posts, I've come to understand that reading/writing to DynamoDB requires using a hadoopRDD - which is different than a RDD in spark - and different from the one in which I am retrieving my s3 file.

How would I go about changing a DataFrame/RDD from a file in s3 to a hadoopRDD so I can send it back up?

I'm using scala and testing out everything in spark-shell.

Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Hi @Willks did you get  the solution to convert rdd to hadoopRDD in Spark-scala.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EMR DynamoDB Connector](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector) implemented by Amazon. It implements both DynamoDBInputFormat and DynamoDBOutputFormat which allows to read and write data from and to DynamoDB.

You can read more about this in this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-your-data-on-amazon-dynamodb-with-apache-spark/).

Comment: Hey, your solution is for streaming data, how about batch data?
(I know I can convert batch to streaming but it has associated costs!)